# How to get row of actual playing item from TableRow to colorize it?

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow, libvlc

I have a little JavaFX Media Player based on libVLC. You can see the source code here: http://bitbucket.org/alibranic/vpfx

I want to colorize the row of the current playing media. Media extends File. I tried many things, but I have to many ideas. I'm not sure, what's the best way to do that.

```
/**
 * selects current playing item in playlist and scrolls to it. Called, when user clicks on Next-Button.
 */
private void selectListItem() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            playList.scrollTo(actualPlayingMediaIndex);
            playList.getSelectionModel().select(actualPlayingMediaIndex);
            // How can I colorize the actual playing media's row now?
        }
    });

}


playList.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Media>, TableRow<Media>>() {

        @Override
        public TableRow<Media> call(TableView<Media> tableView) {
            final TableRow<Media> row = new TableRow<>();
            // do something...
            return row;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see in the gif: I click on play and the current playing row is selected. But it isn't anymore when I click other rows. I want to keep the background color as so long as the media is playing.
[image: gif]

Comment: Why not use css?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32459829/2855515

Comment: The problem is, that when the user clicks on a row it'll be selected. But I want to colorize the media file that is currently playing, not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a property if you want the table to automatically update.  Either make the `actualPlayingMediaIndex` a property or add one the the Media class.

Here's one method.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableStyle extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    SimpleIntegerProperty actualPlayingMediaIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Media> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0;i<100;i++) data.add(new Media("name "+i,"info "+i));

        TableView<Media> tv = new TableView<>(data);
        tv.setEditable(true);

        tv.getColumns().addAll(
                new TableColumn<>("name"),
                new TableColumn<>("info")
        );

        for(TableColumn tc:tv.getColumns()){
            tc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(tc.getText()));
            tc.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            tc.setPrefWidth(100);
        }

        tv.setRowFactory(p -> new TableRow<Media>() {
            @Override protected void updateItem(Media item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
                        getIndex() == actualPlayingMediaIndex.get()
                            ? "-fx-background-color: #ee9999;"
                            : ""
                        , actualPlayingMediaIndex));
            }
        });

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setPromptText("enter 0 - 99");
        tf.setOnAction(e -> {
            actualPlayingMediaIndex.set(Integer.parseInt(tf.getText()));
            tv.scrollTo(actualPlayingMediaIndex.get());
            tv.getSelectionModel().select(actualPlayingMediaIndex.get());
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(tv,tf));
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("tablestyle/cells.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public class Media {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty info = new SimpleStringProperty();


        public StringProperty nameProperty(){return name;}
        public StringProperty infoProperty(){return info;}

        public Media(String nm, String inf) {name.set(nm); info.set(inf);}
    }

}
```